# WebView using offline and online files for a page

Tags: android

I need to make a WebView show some web pages where some parts are offline (on the SD card) and some are online (retrieved via http). For instance, som pictures or javascript files may be local on the sd card, and some may be online. Target is Android 1.6, and I have full control over the server, and the files on the server.

Any ideas?

Comment: I thought we can not load a more than 1 url at the same time on the `webview`. you can achieve it with some design layout to achieve it. please post how does your view should be look like?

Comment: The web pages can have any kind of layout, I just added more information to the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a `ContentProvider` to load the files off the SD card, and use "teh Intarweb" to load the stuff that is online.